# How to get messages of a subscritpion on the cloud pub/sub?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-platform

I want to notice messages remaining which can not be dealed with on subscribers in Cloud Pub/Sub(GCP).
I don't want the pub/sub lose some messages without notifications.

I know that I can't set deadletter queue in Cloud Pub/Sub(GCP).
So I'm trying to develop the tool or batch to watch messages of subscriptions by the api which is projects.subscriptions.pull(https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull?hl=ja).

But I don't know how to call the api with the google-cloud-pubsub:0.26.0-beta.
In addition, I'm developing the batch with scala + play.

I found that I can get messages with "gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions pull" command but I didn't get the publish-time in which the program can check whether the message is not dealed with for a while.

Please help me somebody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cloud Pub/Sub client library does not directly expose the pull method, instead offering an asynchronous API designed for efficiently receiving messages. You could use this asynchronous API to receive your messages. The [Java documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#pubsub-pull-messages-async-java) demonstrates how to create a subscriber using this API. If you have specific reasons to want to call the synchronous pull method, then you'll need to generate the gRPC-based library. You can find the instructions on the [Service APIs Overview page](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/service_apis_overview#grpc_api).

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!!

Comment: I wanted to know the messages which are sent in Pub/Sub. Because I tried to scale subscribers depending on the number of the messages. I will try the gRPC-based library.